# Validation constraint for two validation groups

Tags: validation, symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.7.

I'm trying to make required (NotBlank) a field in my entity class depending on two conditions.  Each condition have its own validation group and I set the correct validation groups in my FormType class.

I tried this: `@Assert\NotBlank(groups={"validationIfCondition1",   "validationIfCondition2"})`

This doesn't work, because it marks the field as required if at least one validation group is used. I would like to mark it as required only if the two validation groups are used.

Is it something doable?

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is impossible. Constraint is used if its groups intersect with form validation groups.
Make group validationIfCondition3, add this group to all fields with groups validationIfCondition1 or validationIfCondition2 and use this group in form ('validation_groups' => 'validationIfCondition3')

Comment: Also you can add constraint Callback @Assert\Callback(callback=function1, groups={"validationIfCondition1",   "validationIfCondition2"}) and in function function1 check groups and value function function1($object, ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
        $groups = $context->getRoot()->getConfig()->getOption('validation_groups');
        var_dump($object);
        var_dump($groups);
    }

Answer (score 0):

if conditions depends on entity attributes, than you can use group_sequence_provider ... and you can with own logic define, which group will be used